# How to make a loop for distance R

Tags: r, loops, filter, location, subset

I have a data frame with locations for example like  this:

```
id       lat         lon
 a  51.50549  -0.0924609
 b  37.80248 -122.416634
 c  51.50609  -0.1238904
```

and so on.

My goal is to make a loop so when one chooses location "a" there will be a subset which will include only locations in the radius of 500km from the "a" and exclude everything which is further than this. I think it should be a loop because there will be a constant change of a picked location so the final subset will be unique for each chosen location.

Comment: What do the locations and final result look like? You need [to make your question reproducible.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610) That said, `dist`—or better `geosphere::distHaversine`—is useful.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you could use geosphere library. I asume your data is a data.table:

```
library(geosphere)
library(data.table)

# asumming your dataframe is named "d"

d <- data.table(d)

# CALCULATE DISTANCE (dist) TO EACH ID (dist_to)

 for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {
      print (d[i,]$id)
      for (j in 1:nrow(d)) {

         d1 <- d[id == d[i,]$id, dist:=distm(c(d[i,]$lon, d[i,]$lat), c(d[j,]$lon, d[j,]$lat), fun = distHaversine)/1000, ]
         d1 <- d1[, dist_to:= d[j,]$id,]
        if(exists('d2')){ d2<-rbindlist(list(d2,d1))} else {d2<-copy(d1)}
  }
}


head(d) 
    id   lat          lon         dist      dist_to
 1:  a 51.50549   -0.0924609    0.000000       a
 2:  b 37.80248 -122.4166340 8623.657407       a
 3:  c 51.50609   -0.1238904    0.000000       a
 4:  a 51.50549   -0.0924609 8625.195873       b
 5:  b 37.80248 -122.4166340 8623.657407       b
 6:  c 51.50609   -0.1238904    0.000000       b

# SELECT DISTANCES LESS THAN 500kms

  d[dist <= 500,]

   id      lat        lon     dist     dist_to
  1:  a 51.50549 -0.0924609 2.178749       c
  2:  c 51.50609 -0.1238904 0.000000       c
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, i tried but i get the error: Item 1 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list       I also tried just to copy and run your code with the df you build  and still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sp` package to calculate distance from degree coordinates:

```
library(sp)

# reproducing your example dataset
id<-c("a","b","c")
lat<-c(51.50549,37.80248,51.50609)
lon<-c(-0.0924609, -122.416634, -0.1238904)
d<-data.frame(id,lat,lon)
d
  id      lat          lon
1  a 51.50549   -0.0924609
2  b 37.80248 -122.4166340
3  c 51.50609   -0.1238904

# x and y coordinates must be in first two columns
d2<-as.matrix(d[,-1])

# spDistsN1 function from sp package calculates distance 
# specify longlat=TRUE if you use degrees, gives result in km
s<-nrow(d)
km2<-lapply(1:s,function(i) d[which(spDistsN1(d2,d2[i,],longlat=TRUE)<=500),])

# the result is in a list, each element corresponding to each record
km2
[[1]]
  id      lat       long
1  a 51.50549 -0.0924609
3  c 51.50609 -0.1238904

[[2]]
  id      lat      long
2  b 37.80248 -122.4166

[[3]]
  id      lat       long
1  a 51.50549 -0.0924609
3  c 51.50609 -0.1238904
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a nested loop seems a bit too much IMHO.

I would propose something around these lines, using only the functionality from the `raster` package:

```
#load package
library(raster)

# create dataframe
df <- data.frame(id=c('a','b','c'), lat=c(51.50549,37.80248,51.50609), lon= c(-0.0924609,-122.416634,-0.1238904))
```

Now, since these are point locations with Latitude and Longitude, I'm creating a projection string with a geographic coordinate system:

```
pj <- CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0')
```

I think the cleanest way would be to define a little function which does exactly what you want (I call it `getPoints`):

```
getPoints <- function(df,id){

  refpoint <- SpatialPoints(df[df$id==id,3:2],proj4string=pj)

  pdist <- pointDistance(refpoint,SpatialPoints(df[,3:2],proj4string=pj),lonlat = T)

  return(df[pdist < 5000,])
}
```

To calculate the distance between points, I'm using the `pointDistance` from the `raster` package. Before/while calculating the distance, I need to convert the coordinates into spatial points with `SpatialPoints` and the defined projection `pj`. I'm selecting the reference point `refpoint` with the `id`supplied to the function and calculate the distance to all points in the dataframe `df`. I'm also calculating the distance to the point itself, so I can index all points with the condition `pdist <= 500000` and it will also return the selected point (since the distance is 0).

On a sidenote, I could have avoided assigning the `refpoint` to a variable, but it's a bit clearer like this.

Finally you could either loop over your point locations

```
for (id_sel in df$id){

print(getPoints(df,id_sel))

}
```

or use lapply, which will conveniently save my results to a list and avoid looping in general:

```
lapply(df$id,function(x) getPoints(df,x))
```